# GeoJson feature property from string to integer

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a markercluster initialized as so:

```
var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJSON(storer, {
        pointToLayer: function (geoJsonPoint, latlng) {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng);
        },
            onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
            style: style,
            fillcolor: style
        });

    markers.addLayer(geoJsonLayer);
    map.addLayer(markers);
```

Each feature has a property called Year, showing when the observations were recorded. However, this property is a string and not an integer. How would I go about changing this property into an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In function onEachFeature overwrite a feature, e.g:

```
(...)
onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
  feature.properties.example = parseInt(feature.properties.example)
}
(...)
```

Comment: Sweet so I incorporated that into my onEachFeature function making feature.properties.time = parseInt(feature.properties.Year) and it works properly. Now I would like to customize ranges of the property to create a time_slider while keeping the markers in cluster form.

Comment: @A.Andre This answer correctly solves the 1st part of your question. Please consider marking it as accepted and to separate your question in 2 different posts, in order to avoid mixing issues.